# Does Parity sync in the background task or does browser have to be open?

Tags: parity-wallet

Does the Parity Wallet sync when background task is running, or do you have to keep the browser window open?  I'm a couple of 100K behind, and I thought I had the background task running continuously.

Can you do a transfer without being fully synced?
Also will the EOS "Claim" Function appear without being fully synced?

Comment: Consider re-asking at [EOS.io site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116927/eosio/visit).

Answer (score 0):

It will run in background but this depends on if u have it set to 'Run on startup" or not.